# Failed initializing the External Content Library with id mm

Tags: ecl, fredhopper, media-manager

I know this is probably asked in a previous thread but I'm getting an issue integrating fredhopper and SDL media manager with Tridion 2013 SP1

The code was running previously and suddenly it stop working today:

> Failed initializing the External Content Library with id mm. One or
>   more errors occurred. One or more errors occurred. No External Content
>   Library provider with the name SDL Media Manager is available.
>
> StackTrace Information Details:    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.DomainModel.MountPoint.get_ContentLibraryContext()
>   at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.EclService2012.GetList(String
>   parentItemId, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1
>   basedOnSchema)    at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] ) 
>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.TransactionSupportInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

Is there any configuration that I am missing due to which I am getting this error?

My Media Manager mount point configuration is-

```
  <ServiceEndPointAddress>[Hidden]</ServiceEndPointAddress>

  <ServiceCertificate storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine" findType="FindByThumbPrint" findValue=[Hidden] />
  <StubFolders>

    <StubFolder id="tcm:4-101-2" />
  </StubFolders>

  <PrivilegedUserName>[hidden]\MTSUser</PrivilegedUserName>
  <EnableUpload administrators="true">

  </EnableUpload>
  <DistributionTypes>

  </DistributionTypes>
</MountPoint>
```

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue on this. We've an ECL setup in SDL Tridion 2013. When we are migrating the same to SDL Web 8.5 it is giving the following error - 2018-09-26 06:16:12,749 [8] ERROR UI.Model - System.Exception: Unable to get the list of items ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Failed initializing the External Content Library with id clp. Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter) at System.S

Comment: Welcome to Tridion StackExchange, please remove your answer and raise it as a separate question with your error message with mentioned this ticket as the reference

Answer (score 5):

If it was running before and not anymore now, and you didn't change anything in the configuration just before it stopped working, then the configuration is fine.

My guess is something happened to the ability of the CMS connecting to the service end point address. Which could be several things:

1. connection issues somewhere between the CMS and the service
2. firewall rules changed
3. certificate expired, revoked or changed (on the server)
4. service down

Comment: Hi Bart, thanks for the help. In this case someone by mistake deleted the dll for External Content Library  from the server. But issue is now resolved.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing the same type of issue and after spending some good amount of time I found that in my visual studio product, the reference dll of the Tridion ECL was set to true for Copy Local property. It was creating a local copy and was referencing this local dll instead of the global one. After setting copy local to false it started working for me.