# ECL Mount Point Error: Failed initializing the External Content Library with id mb

Tags: web8, ecl, permissions

Issue regarding integration of external ECL connector with SDL Web 8.1.1 instance.

[image]

We have two Web 8.1.1 instances that are trying to connect to same (DAM) endpoint:

1 Sandbox = successful
1 Dev = not successful

I am able to successfully get a response from the DAM endpoint from the Content Manager server, so I guess that rules out connectivity issues.

I have viewed similar [questions and answers](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11675/failed-initializing-the-external-content-library-with-id-mm) regarding same Error (but different stack traces then mine below)

Below are logs enabled in "Debug" mode:

```
 2017-01-17 14:30:56,632 [24] ERROR UI.Model - 
 System.Exception: Unable to get the list of items ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: Failed initializing the External Content Library with id mb.

 Server stack trace: 
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

 Exception rethrown at [0]: 
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
 at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.ISessionAwareEclService.GetList(String parentItemUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1 basedOnSchema)
 at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
 at Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.General.GetList(String id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)
 at SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
 at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
 at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
 2017-01-17 14:30:58,504 [24] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id=''
 2017-01-17 14:30:58,504 [24] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Updating element 'tcm:ListActivityInstances'
 2017-01-17 14:30:58,519 [24] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id=''
 2017-01-17 14:30:58,519 [24] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Updating element 'tcm:ListActivityInstances'
 2017-01-17 14:31:03,305 [24] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id=''
 2017-01-17 14:31:03,305 [24] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Updating element 'tcm:ListActivityInstances'
 2017-01-17 14:31:08,586 [24] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id=''
 2017-01-17 14:31:08,586 [24] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Updating element 'tcm:ListActivityInstances'
 2017-01-17 14:31:12,367 [24] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Process response for command 'GetListActivityInstances' id=''
 2017-01-17 14:31:12,367 [24] DEBUG UI.DataExtenders - Updating element 'tcm:ListActivityInstances'
```

Comment: im facing a similar issue on this. We've an ECL setup in SDL Tridion 2013. When we are migrating the same to SDL Web 8.5 it is giving the following error - > 2018-09-26 06:16:12,749 [8] ERROR UI.Model - System.Exception: Unable
> to get the list of items --->
> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
> Failed initializing the External Content Library with id clp.
> > Server stack trace: at
> System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
> reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
> FaultConverter faultConve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the error stack trace, it seems like **user authorization issue**. Are you using same DAM user from the both 8.1.1 instances? If not then check the permission.

Other issue could be thumbprint mismatch, you have to add thumbprint of each of the CM instance to DAM config. In your case, there should be two thumbprints, one for sandbox and one for dev. If it has only sandbox thumbprint then it will not work for dev.