# Failed initializing the External Content Library with id clp

Tags: web8.5, ecl

I'm facing an issue with ECL setup.

We have an ECL setup in SDL Tridion 2013. When we are migrating the same to SDL Web 8.5 it is giving the following error -

> 018-09-26 14:18:36,377 [55] ERROR UI.Model -  System.Exception: Unable
>   to get the list of items --->
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]:
>   Failed initializing the External Content Library with id clp.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message
>   reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version,
>   FaultConverter faultConverter)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime
>   operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action,
>   Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins,
>   Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage
>   methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage
>   message)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.Service.Client.ISessionAwareEclService.GetList(String
>   parentItemUri, Int32 pageIndex, EclItemTypes itemTypes, IEnumerable`1
>   basedOnSchema)    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String
>   id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)    --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.GeneralImpl.GetList(String
>   id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)    at
>   Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.UI.Model.Services.General.GetList(String
>   id, Int32 pageIndex, Filter filter, Int32 columns)    at
>   SyncInvokeGetList(Object , Object[] , Object[] )    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object
>   instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at
>   System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&
>   rpc)    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean
>   isOperationContextSet)

The config file set up is same as the working version and the mts user is being used as a privileged user. 
The working dlls are in place. The local copy property is made to false for the reference dlls as well.
We are using the Tridion.ExternalContentLibrary.V2.dll for this implementation, as suggested in SDL world document.

Everything mentioned in [Failed initializing the External Content Library with id mm](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/11675/failed-initializing-the-external-content-library-with-id-mm) is already taken care of at our end but still facing the issue.

Is something needs to be done differently for Web 8.5? Could someone plz suggest?

Comment: It fails to initialize the provider with ID 'clp'. What ECL provider is that? Do you have it installed correctly? Maybe it has some logging that could be used to troubleshoot the issue further...

Answer (score -1):

We faced a similar issue. This happened because one of the dependent DLLs (log4net.dll), was of incorrect version. For some reason instead of showing the  proper error message, we received the same message as shown above.